# laravel 5.7 login procedure issue

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.7

I have been trying to figure out why is this happening ! I have used the laravel's built in authentication method ,my laravel version is 5.7 and DB is Mysql.The problem is that when I try to login , there is no reaction performed by the server , otherwise , the signup procedure works correctly .I have to mention that when I use these codes with another database built with migrations, everything goes well . Here is my model :

```
    <?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    protected $table = 'person';
    use Notifiable;
    protected $guarded= [];
}
```

Here is my login controller :

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after login.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/';

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    }

    public function username()
    {
        return 'username';
    }
}
```

routers

```
<?php


Auth::routes();
Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index')->name('indexPage');
Route::get('/contact-us', 'ContactUsController@index')->name('contactPage');
Route::get('/about-us', function(){return view('pages.AboutUs');})->name('aboutPage');
Route::resource('/brands' , 'brandController');
```

Comment: What does "there is no reaction performed by the server" mean?

Comment: Please show us your `/routes/web.php` file.

Comment: @Mike I meant when I click on the login button , nothing happens , not login , nor error

Comment: Are you using the default auth views, or did you customize them? You need to determine if this is an HTML/JS issue or a server-side issue.

Comment: no , the default ones . You mean the it may have happened because of my front-end codes error?

Comment: Open up your browser's developer tools (e.g. F12 in Chrome) and click on the Network tab and see if a request is being made to the server when you click on the button. While there also see the Console tab to make sure there are no errors.

Comment: Thanks for your hint , but , The request has been made correctly , and there is no error .

Comment: But the problem persists, is there anyway to overcome this issue?

Comment: If the browser is firing the request, what is the response code? 200?